# QBWebConnector There is no disk in the drive

Tags: quickbooks

I have recently begun to intermittently receive the following error when the QBWebConnector updates:

There is no disk in the drive.  Please insert a disk into drive \Device\Harddisk\DR2.

This does not happen every time (but it is rather frequent).  Also, htting the cancel button multiple times allows the update to successfully run to completion. My hard drives are fine (no errors from check disk, etc).

What is causing this problem and how do I resolve it?  I appreciate your assistance!.

Answer (score 1):

I found this site to be helpful and offer multiple solutions:

http://www.sleeter.com/blog/2013/08/fixing-the-there-is-no-disk-in-the-drive-error/